# How to add boolean attributes to directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, attributes, angularjs-directive

In HTML, there are attributes like the `selected` attribute:

```
<option selected>This option is selected</option>
```

It's either present or not present, which translates to on/off (Boolean).

I can't find a way to create an attribute like this for an AngularJs directive. Is there any way?

An example would be:

```
<modal ng-show="modal.show" with-backdrop> // "with-backdrop" is a boolean attribute.
```

Comment: What have you tried? You can just test for the existence of an attribute in the `attrs` object.

Answer (score 0):

I read again your question and i was wrong. To archieve what you want, you should do the next:

HTML Element:
`<modal id="myModal" ng-show="modal.show" with-backdrop>`

And in your controller:

```
function somethingController() {
  var modalElement = document.querySelector('#myModal');

  // If you want to check that element have your attribute.
  var isMyAttributeSet = modalElement.getAttribute('with-backdrop') !== null;

  // If you want to set up the attribute.
  modalElement.setAttribute('with-backdrop', '');

}
```

The `setAttribute` method requires 2 arguments (attributeName, attributeValue), but if you pass an empty string as second parameter, the attribute would be seen as you want, i have tested it in chrome console :)

Answer (score -1):

It's going to be different depending on what you're doing. In your example, you want to know which option is selected. That would be found by checking the model for the `<select>` to see what's in it. For example:

```
<select data-ng-model="user.defaultThing"
        data-ng-options="thing.id as thing.name for thing in thingCollection">
    <option value="">None</option>
</select>
```

With this setup, any time the selection is changed, the `thing.id` is stored in `user.defaultThing`.

NB: The 'None' option I have there, allows for a null selection.

Now, if you were looking to see if a `checkbox` is checked, it's similar as you'd just see what's in the model it's tied to.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="form.someOption">
```

When you go to process the form, just see if `form.someOption` is `true` or `false`.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was unclear, but I wasn't asking how to check whether a form element was selected or not. I was asking how to create Boolean attributes for angularjs directives that act *like* normal HTML boolean attributes.